# Sumo logic: Override dahsboard time inside query

Tags: sumologic

In sumo logic usually we select the time suing datepicker on top of query. Is there any way I can update these from and to messagetimes inside query.
Use case: I have a dashboard and when I open linked target dashboard from the parent dashboard, the from and to times are always defaulting to 2 mins only. How can I update these from and to times before loading the target dashboard?